# Transferring the data between arrays and missing some values

Tags: c#, arrays

I have one dimensional `String` array with size 200 that Even index cells (0,2,4,6,...) are filled by `Int` and Odd index cells (1,3,5,7,...) are filled by `Float`. In order to add some values to this array I would like to transfer this array to 2 dimensional `String` array with size [100,2] that the first row is filled by the `Int` and the second row is filled by the float.

The problem is during the transmission between the arrays, I miss some values randomly (I get Null instead). I already checked the data to be sure that my data is in the correct format.

```
    int shomar = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < MITNeighborSource.Length; y +=2)                                                                                                        
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Cal.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
          if (MITNeighborSource[y] == Cal[x, 0])
          {
              MITNeighborSourceEdge[0, shomar] = MITNeighborSource[y];   //course ID                                                                                                   
              MITNeighborSourceEdge[1, shomar] = Cal[x, 2];          //output degree                                                                                               
              MITNeighborSourceEdge[2, shomar] = Cal[x, 3];          //Input degree                                                                                                
              MITNeighborSourceEdge[3, shomar] = MITNeighborSource[y+1]; //The cosine similarity                                                                                       
              break;
          }
          if (MITNeighborSource[y] == Cal[x, 1])
          {
              MITNeighborSourceEdge[0, shomar] = MITNeighborSource[y];   //course ID                                                                                                   
              MITNeighborSourceEdge[1, shomar] = Cal[x, 4];          //output degree                                                                                               
              MITNeighborSourceEdge[2, shomar] = Cal[x, 5];          //Input degree                                                                                                
              MITNeighborSourceEdge[3, shomar] = MITNeighborSource[y+1]; //The cosine similarity                                                                                                                                                                      
              break;
          }
        }
shomar++;
    }
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], unfortunately we cannot help you with your code without seeing it.

Comment: @s.m   'Shomar' shows the index for the columns

Comment: I would definitly not introduce one two-dimensional aray for this purpose but simply two independent lists, one  containing the even numbers and one with the odd ones.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The code is edited

Comment: I'm with @HimBromBeere on this one. Plus, what's the actual line that gives you the error? And where's the unit test that exercises this particular piece of code? If there is no such thing, I would strongly recommend you scrap this and write a simple test case first, and then make it pass. It's not like you have nasty dependencies to mock here.

Comment: @s.m. It does not show the error, If found it by using the break point.

Comment: The code is still not complete, the declarations for both `MITNeighborSource` and `Cal` are missing. I rest my case, start writing unit tests and the problem will likely go away. Feed the method a known input, check that whatever comes out is what you expect.

Comment: Most likely neither of the two if-statements match so neither is executed, thus you will get "holes" in the output since you never filled it in. If you fully expected one of the two if statements to match, and it is a problem if neither do, use `if (...) { ... } else if (...) { ... } else throw new Exception(...);` to handle this properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to seperate the 1-D array into 2-D array based on index of items, you can do it like below. Assuming strArray is your 1-D array:

```
        string[] oneDArray = new[] {"200", "2.1", "40", "56.3", "34"};
        var list = oneDArray .ToList();
        var twoDArray = list.GroupBy(x => list.IndexOf(x)%2).Select(x=>x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Here twoDArray will have two arrays containing your even and odd index elements from oneDArray.